# Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': the object is already busy reading Blobs

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I want to upload multiple images. When I choose multiple images photoSelected function is called. I want to use base64 but it shows this error on console.

```
PhotoSelected (e){
       Let files = e.target.files;
       Let reader = new FileReader();
       Let file;
       For (let i=0; I<files.length ; i++){
            file = files [i];
            reader.onload = (file) => {
                   This.product.photo[i] = reader.result;
             }
            reader.readAsDataURL(file)
        }
}
```

Comment: What was the error?

Comment: I would just have uploaded all files with formData if i where you instead of using base64

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you defined the reader outside the for loop and use the same reader within the loop. this results in the reader being busy. You can solve this by creating one reader for each loop in its own scope, using an IIFE.

```
PhotoSelected (e){
       let files = e.target.files;
       let reader = new FileReader();
       let file;
       for (let i=0; I<files.length ; i++){
           (function(file) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = (file) => {
              this.product.photo[i] = reader.result;
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(file)
          })(files[i]);
       }
}
```

Since you are using `let` already and it uses block scope, you could also create a reader each loop using `let`.

```
PhotoSelected (e){
       let files = e.target.files;

       let file;
       for (let i=0; I<files.length ; i++){
            let reader = new FileReader();
            file = files [i];
            reader.onload = (file) => {
                   this.product.photo[i] = reader.result;
             }
            reader.readAsDataURL(file)
        }
}
```